# Silverlight MVVM Implementation not Displaying Content

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

EDIT:
The problem was that my View Models were not public, so the bindings were not found. For some reason they need to be public in Silverlight, even though private view models work for WPF. More detail in my answer below.

---

I am trying to implement an MVVM WPF app in Silverlight, but I have never used Silverlight before. I am struggling to get the bound content to display. I am implementing it almost exactly how I did with WPF, except that the Main bit is a UserControl, not a Window, the app is hosted by a Web Site, and I had to remove the `x:Type` in `DataTemplate` `DataType`

My Website-to-MainPage is working properly, because I can display a text box or something in that page, however the Binding is just not displayed. Any suggestions?

My MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private MainPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

My MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TransformationServices.Silverlight.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TransformationServices.Silverlight.View"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TransformationServices.Silverlight.ViewModel"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TransformationServices.Silverlight"
    Background="#FF2D2D30">
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ViewConverter x:Key="viewConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:InputSelectViewModel">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>
            <!-- This textblock is just for testing. It doesn't work, and neither does the following line-->
            <view:InputSelect/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</UserControl>
```

My MainPageViewModel.cs

```
class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    private ViewModelBase _currentView;

    private List<ViewModelBase> _viewModels;

    private int _viewIndex;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentView)
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        _viewModels = new List<ViewModelBase>();

        // Add view models here
        _viewModels.Add(new InputSelectViewModel());

        _viewIndex = 0;
        CurrentView = _viewModels[_viewIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks valid, the implicit DataTemplate should be displayed. So what could be wrong? Make sure that you work with Silverlight 5 and your browser uses the SL5 runtime, because implicit DataTemplates are only supported since SL5. And another thing you can try poking around the problem: set the template explicitly, just to see if it displays. Like... <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InputSelectTemplate}" ... />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear as though the problem is that my ViewModels were not public. I noticed in the Output the following type of message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get '<Whatever property of View Model>' value ...
```

This message was coming up for every property that I was binding to, including `CurrentView`. After making the View Models public, the bindings worked perfectly. It seems odd to me that Silverlight would need the classes to be public when they worked fine as private for WPF, but this is my first time working with Silverlight, so this intricacy tripped me up. Hopefully this answer can help someone in the future. Anyway, this is the main reason for why the bindings were not working, and thus the `CurrentView` was not being displayed.

Another reason that it was hard for me to debug this issue is that my page was accidentally caching everything, so some of my changes would not display. This link helped me with that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143414/Prevent-your-Silverlight-XAP-File-from-Caching-in